# How to correcly configure libvirt/qemu KVM hypervisor to accept virt-manager client?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos7

I've got a CentOS 7 server KVM with 2 virtual machines running on it. I've been using virt-manager remotely for a couple of weeks without problems... Until yesterday when it froze and I could not connect to the server anymore.
I get the following error message:

```
Cannot connect to libvirt
packet 458961001 bytes received from server too large, want 16777216
ibvirt URI is: qemu+ssh://root@[IP]/system

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/connection.py", line 1020, in _open_thread
    self._backend.open(self._do_creds_password)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtinst/connection.py", line 158, in open
    open_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
libvirtError: packet 458961001 bytes received from server too large, want 16777216
```

Virtual Manager connection is `qemu+ssh://root@[IP]/system`

I don't know why this started to happen. I tried restarting the libvirtd daemon, the VMs and the server itself but the error is still there. I've also tried from another client PC but nothing...

I googled it but I couldn't find a solution :-(

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked your interface MTU values between the virt-manager client, switches, and host? They should match.

Comment: Hey @SmallLoanOf1M, thank you for your suggestion, but I think both have the same MTU. 
On the server i run:

`2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN 
5: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 500`

On my workstation:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000`

Comment: Does Centos have auto update feature enabled?

Comment: Auto update? You mean yum update? I don't know what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found why this happened! 
It was my fault, because I added some code to execute when starting an ssh connection in `.bashrc` file, and that was the large answer received by virt-manager.